# pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN pygame.VIDEORESIZE ERROR?

Tags: python, pygame

I posted a similar question a few days ago but i have refined the problem:
when i have both MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and VIDEORESIZE in the same event loop it doent work... when i click the mouse down it also prints the statement which should only get printed when the MOUSEBUTTONUP event occurs.... TRY it your selves this problem is killing me..

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from sys import exit

LEFT = 1
size = 520,630
running = 1
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size, RESIZABLE, 32)
#screen = pygame.display.set_mode((size))
while running:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      running = 0
    if event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
      size = event.size
      pygame.display.set_caption("Window resized to "+str(event.size)) 
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == LEFT:
       print "You pressed the left mouse button at (%d, %d)" % event.pos
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and event.button == LEFT:
       print "You released the left mouse button at (%d, %d)" % event.pos

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size, RESIZABLE, 32)
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you should reinitialize your display in every update step... `screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size, RESIZABLE, 32)` should probably be called only, in the if of the `VIDEORESIZE`. Not exactly sure though...

Answer (score 0):

Don't update the screen at every event, it slows down your program considerably. It's so slow on my computer I can't make any sense of the mouse events. Just moving a couple of lines of your code fixes that and it runs fine.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from sys import exit

LEFT = 1
size = 520,630
running = 1
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size, RESIZABLE, 32)
while running:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      running = 0
    if event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
      size = event.size
      pygame.display.set_caption("Window resized to "+str(event.size)) 
      screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
      pygame.display.flip()
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == LEFT:
       print "You pressed the left mouse button at (%d, %d)" % event.pos
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and event.button == LEFT:
       print "You released the left mouse button at (%d, %d)" % event.pos
```

Comment: Thanks! this works.. However there is one small problem with this bit of code. If i make it winder larger before making it smaller i get the following error "this application has requested the runtime to terminate it in an unusual way . please contact the application's support team for more information" but if i make it smaller first it works really well! any ideas why that is??

Comment: Try removing the `screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size, RESIZABLE, 32)` in your loop. You only need to do that once. I edited my post and removed it in the answer. Maybe that will help.